# How to Delay in Linux Kernel Module Critical Section

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I need to add a short delay in a USB kernel module to avoid extremely rare kernel panics on bootup for a small embedded Linux device. The problematic code is below. If I put a prink in the code, the device runs all night successfully where it used to fail before. I want to add a small delay but usleep_range and msleep cause a Kernel traceback "Scheduling While Atomic". How can I add a delay in this section of code without sleeping? Is a while loop the way to do it?

```
usb_hub_for_each_child(udev, chix, childdev) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "r8a66597: Start USB Discover\n");
    //usleep_range(10000, 11000);
    //preempt_disable();
    //msleep(1);
    collect_usb_address_map(childdev, map);
    //usleep_range(10000, 11000);
    printk(KERN_ERR "r8a66597: Stop USB Discover\n");
    //msleep(1);
    //preempt_enable();
}
```

Comment: You need to find a root cause of the race condition you have in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Header [linux/delay.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/delay.h) provides functions for **delay without sleep**. These functions can be used in interrupt (atomic) context:

- ndelay(ns) - wait for given number of nanoseconds,
- udelay(us) - wait for given number of microseconds,
- mdelay(ms) - wait for given number of milliseconds.